# Displaying large sequence of number for x axis in barplot

Tags: r

While plotting bargraph i want to display label of large sequence of numbers for x-axis.I figured by using names.arg=c() .But  for displaying large sequence of numbers such as from 1 to 50 in x -axis i  have to type all the numbers such as names.arg=c("1","2","3","4"------"50").

Is there any method to display such sequences by other method such as 1:50 or any other method so that i need not type all the numbers.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: does `names.arg=1:50` not work for you? or maybe `names.arg=as.character(1:50)`?

Comment: @StephLocke is right. Seems like as.character(1:50) is exactly what you need. It worked fine when I've tested it.

Comment: @StephLocke thanks it worked.Mistakenly i have placed 1:50 in quote.After removing quote it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `names.arg=1:50` or if you'd like them to have a text datatype `names.arg=as.character(1:50)`

(follow up from comments)